# AngularJS $resource creating new object instead of updating object

Tags: rest, angularjs

```
// Set up the $resource
$scope.Users = $resource("http://localhost/users/:id");

// Retrieve the user who has id=1
$scope.user = $scope.Users.get({ id : 1 }); // returns existing user

// Results
{"created_at":"2013-03-03T06:32:30Z","id":1,"name":"testing","updated_at":"2013-03-03T06:32:30Z"}

// Change this user's name
$scope.user.name = "New name";

// Attempt to save the change 
$scope.user.$save();

// Results calls POST /users and not PUT /users/1
{"created_at":"2013-03-03T23:25:03Z","id":2,"name":"New name","updated_at":"2013-03-03T23:25:03Z"}
```

I would expect that this would result in a PUT to /users/1 with the changed attribute. But it's instead POST to /users and it creates a new user (with a new id along with the new name).

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

```
AngularJS v1.0.5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you just need to tell the $resource, how he has to bind the route-parameter ":id" with the JSON Object:

```
$scope.Users = $resource("http://localhost/users/:id",{id:'@id'});
```

This should work,
regards

Comment: Thanks, 90% there, it POSTs to /users/1 now with the updated user. But now how to make it PUT instead of POST? Very close.

Comment: I guess it POST by design. I'll have to override "save" to POST when it's a new resource and PUT when it's an update to an existing resource.
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: to answer my question about PUT instead of POST, $resource("/users/:id", { 'id' : '@id' }, {update:{method:'PUT'}}); does the trick for PUT. Just call User.update(user) or user.$update in the manner you would User.save(user) and user.$save.

Comment: @MarkPeterson I think you should post the full answer to make it clear for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer. It worked in the end for me too.
As a side note, I was using .NET WEB API and my entity has an Id property (UPPER CASE "I").
The PUT and DELETE worked only after I used the following:

```
$scope.Users = $resource("http://localhost/users/:Id",{Id:'@Id'});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using .NET won't impact whether you need to add `{Id:'@Id'}`